# Insertar datos desde EXCEL a una tabla en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

Tengo una hoja en Excel 2016 que contiene varias columnas con información de mis clientes; la ruta del archivo es "D:\Clientes.xlsx".

Luego tengo una tabla "tb_clientes" en la Base de Datos "bd_comercial" (SQL Server 2008 R2) con los mismos nombres, orden, y cantidad de columnas que el archivo Excel.

Lo que quisiera saber es si, a través de un query, puedo insertar los datos que aparecen en el archivo Excel a mi tabla en SQL Server de manera automática, todos los días 1 de cada mes.

Por ahí me comentaron que se puede hacer a través de un Job, espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: primero tienes que ver como exportar datos desde otra fuente usando Sql Server Management Studio y luego configuras el JOB para que se ejecute con la frecuencia que deseas.

Answer (score 1):

Considero que la forma correcta y más sencilla de realizar lo que requieres es a través de SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS).

Allí podrías definir la carga de los datos, algunas transformaciones que requieras y posteriormente automatizar la carga periódica a través del SQL Server Agent.

Si no conoces la herramienta, esta guía te podría orientar de forma inicial: [link](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/usando-paquetes-ssis-para-importar-datos-de-ms-excel-en-una-base-de-datos/).